# Direct link using Shopify's Buy Button

Tags: javascript, html, shopify, buybutton.js

I have a website I designed in HTML5 and I want to link to a product checkout page but I really don't want to use all the BuyButton's formatting and all the extras.

Here's the code that Shopify is telling me to use:

```
<div id='product-component-xxx'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
(function () {
  var scriptURL = 'https://sdks.shopifycdn.com/buy-button/latest/buy-button-storefront.min.js';
  if (window.ShopifyBuy) {
    if (window.ShopifyBuy.UI) {
      ShopifyBuyInit();
    } else {
      loadScript();
    }
  } else {
    loadScript();
  }
  function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.async = true;
    script.src = scriptURL;
    (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(script);
    script.onload = ShopifyBuyInit;
  }
  function ShopifyBuyInit() {
    var client = ShopifyBuy.buildClient({
      domain: 'xxx.myshopify.com',
      storefrontAccessToken: 'xxx',
    });
    ShopifyBuy.UI.onReady(client).then(function (ui) {
      ui.createComponent('product', {
        id: 'xxx',
        node: document.getElementById('product-component-xxx'),
        moneyFormat: '%24%7B%7Bamount%7D%7D',
        options: {
  "product": {
    "styles": {
      "product": {
        "@media (min-width: 601px)": {
          "max-width": "calc(25% - 20px)",
          "margin-left": "20px",
          "margin-bottom": "50px"
        }
      },
      "button": {
        "font-weight": "bold",
        "font-size": "18px",
        "padding-top": "17px",
        "padding-bottom": "17px",
        ":hover": {
          "background-color": "#ff0042"
        },
        "background-color": "#ca0027",
        ":focus": {
          "background-color": "#ff0042"
        },
        "border-radius": "7px",
        "padding-left": "100px",
        "padding-right": "100px"
      },
      "quantityInput": {
        "font-size": "18px",
        "padding-top": "17px",
        "padding-bottom": "17px"
      }
    },
    "buttonDestination": "checkout",
    "contents": {
      "img": false,
      "title": false,
      "price": false
    },
    "text": {
      "button": "Buy now"
    }
  },
  "productSet": {
    "styles": {
      "products": {
        "@media (min-width: 601px)": {
          "margin-left": "-20px"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "modalProduct": {
    "contents": {
      "img": false,
      "imgWithCarousel": true,
      "button": false,
      "buttonWithQuantity": true
    },
    "styles": {
      "product": {
        "@media (min-width: 601px)": {
          "max-width": "100%",
          "margin-left": "0px",
          "margin-bottom": "0px"
        }
      },
      "button": {
        "font-weight": "bold",
        "font-size": "18px",
        "padding-top": "17px",
        "padding-bottom": "17px",
        ":hover": {
          "background-color": "#ff0042"
        },
        "background-color": "#ca0027",
        ":focus": {
          "background-color": "#ff0042"
        },
        "border-radius": "7px",
        "padding-left": "100px",
        "padding-right": "100px"
      },
      "quantityInput": {
        "font-size": "18px",
        "padding-top": "17px",
        "padding-bottom": "17px"
      }
    },
    "text": {
      "button": "Add to cart"
    }
  },
  "cart": {
    "styles": {
      "button": {
        "font-weight": "bold",
        "font-size": "18px",
        "padding-top": "17px",
        "padding-bottom": "17px",
        ":hover": {
          "background-color": "#ff0042"
        },
        "background-color": "#ca0027",
        ":focus": {
          "background-color": "#ff0042"
        },
        "border-radius": "7px"
      }
    },
    "text": {
      "total": "Subtotal",
      "button": "Checkout"
    },
    "popup": false
  },
  "toggle": {
    "styles": {
      "toggle": {
        "font-weight": "bold",
        "background-color": "#ca0027",
        ":hover": {
          "background-color": "#ff0042"
        },
        ":focus": {
          "background-color": "#ff0042"
        }
      },
      "count": {
        "font-size": "18px"
      }
    }
  }
},
      });
    });
  }
})();
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

But I really want just a simply HTML link to go to the product check out page

Buy Now

How can I do this? Is there anyway to keep the styling that I want and use and just have the buy button open the link?

Thanks

Comment: you make design changes to `BUY NOW` using the existing code, but you can't modify the default steps or process, if you want to add a direct link then you use a direct add to cart link to add a product page, but the same is not direct to the checkout page.

Answer (score 0):

Here two really easy options:

1. just use the checkout API it's a rest API, you can use it with fetch, axios, ajax [here more details](https://shopify.dev/tutorials/get-started-with-js-buy-sdk)
2. if you need something more simple you can do even a classic form post using the [ajax cart api](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/ajax-api/reference/cart) you need the product's variant Id plus the quantity.

to find the variant's ID, on shopify admin go to the product page and add .xml at the end.
change

```
your-store.myshopify.com/admin/products/2373831663781
```

to

```
your-store.myshopify.com/admin/products/2373831663781.xml
```

after that you can do something like this:

```
await fetch('your-store.myshopify.com/cart/add.js', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    id: 'XXX',
    quantity: 1,
  })
});
```

it response with a json, or you can use `/cart/add` on a form submit, it will redirect to checkout.